# Rectangle CornerRadius

Tags: wpf, xaml, blend

This is somewhat a general question about rectangles with border radii. I'm working with a developer that's taking my Photoshop comps and applying the designs to a prototype in Blend. They've told me that in Blend it's not possible to create a rectangle with only 2 curved corners. Supposedly you have to have all 4 corners with a border radius or none at all. Ideally I'd like only the top left and right corners with a border radius of 10 and the bottom edges without a curve. I'd just like to know if this is possible to do.

[image: Refer to example below]

Comment: Haha this sounds really familiar, if your dev's name is James tell him to contact me. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Using Clip :** [RectangleGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rectanglegeometry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<Rectangle Fill="Blue" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="200" Width="200">
    <Rectangle.Clip>        
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,20,200,200"  RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20"/>                                                         
    </Rectangle.Clip>
</Rectangle>
```

**Using VisualBrush**

```
 <Rectangle>
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Border CornerRadius="50,50,0,0"  Width="300" Height="200" Background="Navy"></Border>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

It is not be possible with Rectangle. But it is possible using Border.

```
<Border Width="230" Height="100" CornerRadius="10 10 0 0" Background="red"/>
```

The values will be applied in this fashion - **"TopLeft TopRight BottomRight BottomLeft"**